# Maze backtracking with DFS

Tags: java, algorithm, search, graph-theory, maze

i am having trouble determining the algorithm for backtracking in a maze using DFS as a starting point,after which i want to include a heuristic cost to determine shortest path.Given a maze of 0 and 1 my hunter node have to find the prey node.I have done what i can however when it reaches a dead end it will "jump" to the next walkable node in my stack, which is not what i want, i need to be able to backtrack to that walkable node and from there continue exploring the maze.

1 is Path,0 is wall.

```
0001000001
0111110101
0100010101
0111011101
0001010001
0111010101
0100010101
0111011101
0001000001
1111111111
```

Main class:

```
 public class main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            //create maze from file
            MazeGenerator mazeGenerationTest = new MazeGenerator();
            mazeGenerationTest.generateFromTextFile();

            //create hunter and prey nodes
            Node hunter = new Node(0,3);
            Node prey = new Node(0,9);
            //setup maze
            MazeTraversal mazeTraverse = new MazeTraversal(mazeGenerationTest.getNodeGrid(),hunter,prey);
            mazeTraverse.setCols(mazeGenerationTest.getCols());
            mazeTraverse.setRows(mazeGenerationTest.getRows());
            //run algo
            mazeTraverse.dfs();
            mazeGenerationTest.seeMaze();

        }

    }
```

Maze Generator class for reading from text file

```
   public class MazeGenerator {

        private Node nodeGrid[][];
        private ArrayList<Node> adjList = new ArrayList<Node>();
        private int rows = 0;
        private int cols = 0;
        public MazeGenerator(){

        }

        public void generateFromTextFile(){
            BufferedReader br = null;
            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(CONSTANTS.MAZE_PATH));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = br.readLine();
                cols = line.length();
                while (line != null) {
                    rows++;

                    sb.append(line);
                    sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
                    line = br.readLine();
                }

                br.close();
                //set 2d array of node according to rows and cols read from text file, and init nodes
                setNodeGrid(getRows(),getCols(),sb.toString());
                //seeMaze();
                //manualAdjList();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        public Node[][] getNodeGrid() {
            return nodeGrid;
        }

        /***
         * Creates and initializes a 2d node grid.
         * @param rows The number of rows for initializing the 2d array
         * @param cols The number of columns for initializing the 2d array
         * @param mazeTxt The string of maze text read from the file
         */
        public void setNodeGrid(int rows, int cols,String mazeTxt) {
            this.nodeGrid = new Node[rows][cols];
            int nodesAccessed = 0;
            //initialise nodes into grid 
            for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++){
                for(int c = 0; c < cols; c++){
                    if(mazeTxt.charAt(nodesAccessed) != '\n' && mazeTxt.charAt(nodesAccessed) != '\r'){
                        if(mazeTxt.charAt(nodesAccessed) == '1'){//if node is 1 == path
                            nodeGrid[r][c] = new Node(r,c,false);
                        }else{
                            nodeGrid[r][c] = new Node(r,c,true);//node == 0 is wall
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        --c;
                    }

                    nodesAccessed++;
                }
            }

        }

        public int getRows() {
            return rows;
        }


        public int getCols() {
            return cols;
        }

        public void seeMaze(){
            for(int r = 0; r < getRows();r++){
                for(int c = 0; c< getCols();c++){
                    getNodeGrid()[r][c].toString();

                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Maze traversal class for the algorithm of traversing

```
    public MazeTraversal(Node[][] nodeGrid,Node hunter,Node prey){
        this.nodeGrid = nodeGrid;
        this.hunter = hunter;
        this.prey = prey;

    }
    public void dfs(){

        Stack<Node> stack = new Stack<Node>();
        Node hunterNode = null;
        Node preyNode = null;
        Node currentNode = null;

        hunterNode = nodeGrid[getHunter().getX()][getHunter().getY()];
        preyNode = nodeGrid[getPrey().getX()][getPrey().getY()];
        //Add hunter node to stack
        stack.push(hunterNode);
        System.out.println("Pushed Start-"+hunterNode.toString());
            while(!stack.isEmpty()){//while there are items in the stack

                currentNode = stack.pop();//pop  into currentNode
                System.out.println("Popped-"+currentNode.toString());
                if(currentNode.equals(preyNode)){
                    System.out.println("Found!");
                    return;
                }
                if(!currentNode.isDiscovered()){//if the current node is not yet discovered
                    currentNode.setDiscovered(true);//we mark it as discovered
                    generateNeighboursForNode(currentNode);//discover all neighbours of currentNode and add it to the nodes neighbour list

                    for(Node neighbour : currentNode.getNeighboursList()){//for all neighbour of current node
                        if(neighbour.getPredecessor()==null)//we do this check so the next node cannot replace the parent node
                            neighbour.setPredecessor(currentNode);//and add currentNode as their parentNode.
                        if(!neighbour.equals(currentNode.getPredecessor()))//if this neighbour is not equal to the parent
                        {
                            stack.push(neighbour);// we push to stack, so we do not add the parent into the stack again
                            System.out.println("Pushed-"+neighbour.toString());
                        }
                    }
                }else{//discovered
                    System.out.println("This node is discovered ! " +currentNode.toString());
                    boolean allDiscovered = true;//assume all is discovered
                    for(Node neighbour : currentNode.getNeighboursList()){
                        if(!neighbour.isDiscovered()){//for each neighbour that is not yet discovered;push neighbour
                            stack.push(neighbour);
                            System.out.println("Pushed-"+neighbour.toString());
                            allDiscovered = false;//as long as one neighbour is not yet discovered
                        }
                    }
                    if(allDiscovered){//if all neigbour is discovered
                        stack.push(currentNode.getPredecessor());//backtrack to parent;push parent 
                        System.out.println("Pushed-"+currentNode.toString());
                    }

                }

            }//while end
    }

    public Node getHunter() {
        return hunter;
    }

    public void setHunter(Node hunter) {
        this.hunter = hunter;
    }

    public Node getPrey() {
        return prey;
    }

    public void setPrey(Node prey) {
        this.prey = prey;
    }
    public int getRows() {
        return rows;
    }

    public void setRows(int rows) {
        this.rows = rows;
    }

    public int getCols() {
        return cols;
    }

    public void setCols(int cols) {
        this.cols = cols;
    }

    public MazeTraversal(Node[][] nodeGrid){
        this.nodeGrid = nodeGrid;

    }

    public void generateNeighboursForNode(Node node){
        //add adj nodes
        int nodeX = node.getX();
        int nodeY = node.getY();

        Node currentNode = nodeGrid[nodeX][nodeY];

        if(currentNode.isWall()){//if we are looking at a wall we return
            return;
        }
        Node rightNode = null;
        if (nodeY < cols - 1){ // the condition for the existence of a right node
            rightNode = nodeGrid[nodeX][nodeY+1];
            if(!rightNode.isWall()){
                currentNode.addNeighbor(rightNode);
            }
        }

        Node bottomNode = null;
        if (nodeX < rows - 1){
            bottomNode = nodeGrid[nodeX+1][nodeY];// the condition for the existence of a bottom node
            if(!bottomNode.isWall()){
                currentNode.addNeighbor(bottomNode);
            }
        }

        Node leftNode = null;
        if (nodeX > 0){
            leftNode = nodeGrid[nodeX-1][nodeY];// the condition for the existence of a left node
            if(!leftNode.isWall()){
                currentNode.addNeighbor(leftNode);
            }
        }

        Node topNode = null;
        if (nodeY > 0){
            topNode = nodeGrid[nodeX][nodeY-1];// the condition for the existence of a top node
            if(!topNode.isWall()){
                currentNode.addNeighbor(topNode);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Generating neighbours "+node.toString());
    }
}
```

The node class

```
public class Node {

    private Node predecessor;//previous node
    private boolean isWall;
    private boolean isDiscovered;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private ArrayList<Node> neighbours = new ArrayList<Node>();
    //for a star
    private int hCost;
    public Node(int x , int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.predecessor = null;
        this.isWall = false;
        this.isDiscovered = false;
    }
    public Node(int x , int y,boolean isWall){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.predecessor = null;
        this.isWall = isWall;
        this.isDiscovered = false;
    }
    //add a neighbor to this cell, and this cell as a neighbor to the other
    public void addNeighbor(Node other) {
        if (!this.neighbours.contains(other)) { // avoid duplicates
            this.neighbours.add(other);


        }
    }
    public Node getPredecessor() {
        return predecessor;
    }
    public void setPredecessor(Node predecessor) {
        this.predecessor = predecessor;
    }
    public boolean isWall() {
        return isWall;
    }
    public void setWall(boolean isWall) {
        this.isWall = isWall;
    }
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int gethCost() {
        return hCost;
    }
    public void sethCost(int hCost) {
        this.hCost = hCost;
    }


    public boolean isDiscovered() {
        return isDiscovered;
    }
    public void setDiscovered(boolean isDiscovered) {
        this.isDiscovered = isDiscovered;
    }
    public ArrayList<Node> getNeighboursList() {
        return neighbours;
    }

    public String coordStr(){
        return "("+this.x+","+this.y+")";
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (!(other instanceof Node)) return false;
        Node otherCell = (Node) other;
        return (this.x == otherCell.x && this.y == otherCell.y);
    }


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // random hash code method designed to be usually unique
        return this.x + this.y * 256;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String coords ="";
        String parent = "";
        String neighbour ="";
        String discovered ="";

        coords = "Node:"+coordStr();
        if(getPredecessor() !=null)
            parent = " Parent Node:"+getPredecessor().coordStr();

        neighbour = " Neighbours:";
        for(Node n: getNeighboursList()){
            neighbour+= n.coordStr()+n.isDiscovered;
        }
        discovered = " isDiscovered():"+isDiscovered();
        return coords+discovered+parent+neighbour;
    } 

}
```

To explain what i meant by the jump, from my debugging messages, you can see that from 9,0 it will jump to 9,4 which should not be the case rather it should go back to 9,3 and from there continue to 9,4

Pushed-Node:(9,3) isDiscovered():false Parent Node:(8,3) Neighbours:

Popped-Node:(9,3) isDiscovered():false Parent Node:(8,3) Neighbours:

Generating neighbours Node:(9,3) isDiscovered():true Parent Node:(8,3) 
Neighbours:(9,4)false(8,3)true(9,2)false

Pushed-Node:(9,4) isDiscovered():false Parent Node:(9,3) Neighbours:

Pushed-Node:(9,2) isDiscovered():false Parent Node:(9,3) Neighbours:

Popped-Node:(9,2) isDiscovered():false Parent Node:(9,3) Neighbours:

Generating neighbours Node:(9,2) isDiscovered():true Parent Node:(9,3) Neighbours:(9,3)true(9,1)false

Pushed-Node:(9,1) isDiscovered():false Parent Node:(9,2) Neighbours:

Popped-Node:(9,1) isDiscovered():false Parent Node:(9,2) Neighbours:

Generating neighbours Node:(9,1) isDiscovered():true Parent Node:(9,2) Neighbours:(9,2)true(9,0)false

Pushed-Node:(9,0) isDiscovered():false Parent Node:(9,1) Neighbours:

Popped-Node:(9,0) isDiscovered():false Parent Node:(9,1) Neighbours:

Generating neighbours Node:(9,0) isDiscovered():true Parent Node:(9,1) Neighbours:(9,1)true

Popped-Node:(9,4) isDiscovered():false Parent Node:(9,3) Neighbours:

Generating neighbours Node:(9,4) isDiscovered():true Parent Node:(9,3) Neighbours:(9,5)false(9,3)true

Pushed-Node:(9,5) isDiscovered():false Parent Node:(9,4) Neighbours:

Popped-Node:(9,5) isDiscovered():false Parent Node:(9,4) Neighbours:

Generating neighbours Node:(9,5) isDiscovered():true Parent Node:(9,4) Neighbours:(9,6)false(9,4)true

Pushed-Node:(9,6) isDiscovered():false Parent Node:(9,5) Neighbours:

Popped-Node:(9,6) isDiscovered():false Parent Node:(9,5) Neighbours:

Comment: DFS isn't the best algorithm to find the shortest path in a maze. Use BFS instead.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of pushing *all* of the neighbors/children, you should just push the nodes that need to be revisited, and then determine which is the next neighbor/child to go to when that node gets popped off.  By keeping both nodes-to-be-visited and nodes-to-be-revisited on the same stack, it is no wonder that, at some point, they get confused.